# Renewable sources

Tags: oxygen-not-included

I have made a decent base and realised that I had 3 geysers nearby which led me to wonder how many renewable resources/sources (**not** electricity) there are in the game. I have come up with the following list:

Animals
Geysers/vents/volcanoes/etc.
Meteors
The printing pod

The question I am asking is **Are there any other renewable sources in the current game (QoL. Mk.3)?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before the Launch Update everything apart from wolframite and tungsten is renewable. After the Launch Update everything seems to be renewable.

Lists below show data from before the Launch Update.

There are geysers/volcanos for:

> - liquids
>
>   - water/steam
>   - polluted water
>   - magma/lava
>   - iron, copper, gold (liquid)
>   - oil
> - Gases
>
>   - carbon dioxide
>   - hydrogen
>   - polluted oxygen
>   - chlorine
>   - natural gas

out of those resources you can already transform most resources.

Additionally you can bring almost anything back from space depending on the visited planet.

(only listing resources)

> - Coal based
> - Refined Carbon / Coal / Diamond
> - Metal
>
>   - Ore Iron / Copper
>   - Refined Iron / Copper / Steel
> - Stones
>
>   - Obsidian / Sedimentary Rock / Igneous Rock / Regolith / Mafic Rock / Abyssalite / Magma
> - Glass
> - Water / Ice
> - Polluted Water
> - Gases
>
>   - Solid Carbon Dioxide / Oxygen / Methane
>   - Carbon Dioxide / Oxygen / Natural Gas / Hydrogen
> - Organic
>
>   - Slime / Algae / Dirt

And finally you can now print some elements and other stuff with your printing pod.

(only listing resources)

> - Organics
>
>   - Dirt
>   - Algae
>   - Fertilizer
> - Water / Ice
> - Oxylite
> - Metal
>
>   - Ore (Copper, Gold Amalgram)
>   - Refined (Copper, Gold, Iron)
>   - Steel
> - Plastic

And last but not least. Since you are already sending rockets to space, you can also catch the exhaust of your rockets and the meteor showers for some additional carbon dioxide and steam.

And finally least (thanks to @ThisRandomGuy), flatulent dupes will also produce natural gas without any required input (apart from the obligatory food and oxygen).

Comment: How do you produce metal ore?

Comment: Space Rockets and maybe the printer. Excluding wolframite of course.

Comment: Technically, duplicates are a renewable  source of natural gas if they have the flatulent trait

Comment: added tungsten as another non-renewable resource.

Comment: update after the latest patch (launch update): to my knowledge all resources are renewable now even the newly added ones. a tungsten/wolframite planet has been added as well.

Comment: The one thing to watch for is that the Tungsten planet ("Glimmering Planet") isn't a guaranteed spawn, so you **can** still have maps with some non-renewable (or absent!) resources.